# How to implement transparent layer to highlight UI elements in Android

Tags: android

Is there any good library or tutorial about how to implement what i call an application tutorial feature.

When a user open some activity for the first time - the activity doesn't stops but some layer is shown above with custom UI and some elements (that are being highlighted) from the activity are still visible.

If my words seem unclear, just look at the first screenshots here: 
Like you can see on the first screens here http://www.android-app-patterns.com/apps/app/209

The only library I found is https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView but it doesn't allow arbitrary ui, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

I work that like this:

1. Create fragment in activity.
2. Create style for that fragment (transparent,picture and...).
3. Create SharedPreference method and save status true when user first time open app ,and show fragment.
4. Set in onCreate : if (status!=true){ - show fragment -}

Comment: I mean, how do you create such a layout, and not how to save its state in preferences